# If $a+b+c=3,$ show $a+b+c\geq ab+bc+ac$ by using AM-GM

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

A am having issues with a problem that states: let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $a + b + c = 3$. Show that $$a^bb^cc^a\le1$$

As this was an example problem, a solution path was provided but I am confused as to why the solution works. It writes:
$$1=\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$
$$\ge\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}$$
$$\ge (a^bb^cc^a)^{\frac{1}{a+b+c}}$$

I understand how weighted AM-GM could show the second inequality but I can't seem to understand how one can show $a+b+c \ge ab+bc+ca$ which is what the first inequality implies.

Btw: at this point in the text, they have only proved AM-GM and weighted AM-GM. I can think of a way to show this using Chebyshev's Inequality but I was hoping to try to understand what the text meant by this specific solution path.

Comment: use $${(a+b+c)}^2\ge 3(ab+bc+ac)$$ $$\iff a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ac$$

Comment: sure, but how do we know $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab + bc + ac$?

Comment: using that $a+b+c=3$, $$(a+b+c)^2\ge 3(ab+bc+ac) = (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)$$

Comment: I am confused as to how that step isn't just assuming $a+b+c \ge ab+bc+ac$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)$$

but, by $MA\ge MG$:  $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab, a^2+c^2\ge 2ac, b^2+c^2\ge 2bc$, what gives you

$$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+ac+bc.$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Oh dang, yeah that makes sense. Thanks